# function for each element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ive got a function:

```
setInterval ( doSomething, 100 );

function doSomething ( )
{
$("#i_msl").animate({ top: "-150px",}, 1000 ).delay(1000);
$("#i_msl").animate({ top: "-300px",}, 1000 ).delay(1000); 
$("#i_msl").animate({ top: "0px",}, 1000 ).delay(1000); 
}
```

but it works only for one element. How can I make it work for all elements with #i_msl on page?

Comment: `id`s are supposed to be unique on a page. In other words you should expect `$("#i_msl")` to return a jQuery object with one matched element.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning an ID to multiple elements. You can't do that. Try giving them a class instead:

```
class="i_msl"
```

You can access it with $(".i_msl")

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You can only have one unique `id` per page. Change it from `id` to `class`, and target by `$('.i_msl')`.

Answer (score 2):

The selector `#i_msl` is for a specific ID; these are supposed to be unique on the page. Instead, assign each element a unique class, such as:

```
class="my-class"
```

Then just select them using a class selector:

```
$(".my-class").animate({ top: "-150px",}, 1000 ).delay(1000);
$(".my-class").animate({ top: "-300px",}, 1000 ).delay(1000); 
$(".my-class").animate({ top: "0px",}, 1000 ).delay(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

`#i_msl` is an ID selector. You can (should) only have a single item on the page with a particular id. If you need multiple elements to match the selector, use a class: `.i_msl`

Also, `setInterval` will be called every `100ms` which may cause issues with execution when your animation takes longer than the interval.